# 'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command or operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I tried to create React Project but create-react-app my-app command is not working..please help

here is command

> npm install -g create-react-app
>
> create-react-app my-app

[here is screenshort of my commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxSWx.png)

Comment: please add your commands as code block in here and not as link.

Comment: Did you try googling it? Seems a very common error on Windows and very simple to solve.

Comment: yes i googling but i failed to solve the problem then i submit the question here..

Comment: Please check if `C:\User\<your user id>\AppData\Roaming\npm` in your %PATH%.

Comment: yes i gave the path variable..

Answer (score 5):

Why is the screenshot dating back 25 Dec 2017. You need to re install the latest version of node and try latest version of React.

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Then do

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 3):

First Check your Node version. if your node version is 8 or greater then 8 then use
 **'npx create-react-app my-app'** 
In the above version we need to change only one word that is ***npx***
You don't need to do another things. I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

[check this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2aKy.png) and run this:

```
npm install create-react-app

npx create-react-app my
```

Answer (score 1):

May be your npm is not in your environment variable path. Please try

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try `react-native init` instead of `create-react-app`.
   Like `react-native init my-app`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
npx create-react-app bla-bla
```